# Drivers installation problems (Acer Aspire Switch 10E)

Tags: windows, driver

My laptop model is SW3-16-15TV, I installed windows 10 home on it and I don't have sound, wi-fi, and other features... I found drivers for it here https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6460?b=1 . I download only this driver https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JXTL.png because contains all other drivers. I tried to install other drivers one by one but I can't. Some of them throw errors and some of them installed but nothing happend. For example I installed audio driver, but after I reboot my pc I don't have sound and the same problem. I entered in BIOS and from there I found laptop serial number and searched that drivers... When I want to run Platform Drivers Installer it throw me this error:

> a system reboot is required to rollback changes made

I didn't know why it throw me this error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the how to fix drivers! Device Manager -> uninstalled driver (with yellow or red attention sign). [Click on Browse my computer for...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWASj.png) -> [Browse driver path, check that checkbox and click Next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQguI.png) !